# MySQL slave becoming a replication master for additional slaves

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have MySQL servers A, B, C, and D. Server A is the MySQL master who receives the write traffic, and my applications look at B + C for reads (current slaves). I have replication forwarding ALL database events from A --> B and then from B ---> C. Server B is a slave to A, but a "master" to C. There are about 14 databases being tracked in the bin-logs. So, I would like to setup replication to AWS Aurora (the future D server), but I only want to replicate ONE database to it, from server C. So my setup would ideally look like this:

A ----> B ----> C ----> D (aws aurora w/ 1 database)

How do I tell server C to become a replication master and only replicate ONE database to server D (aws aurora)? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of this answer, you want to replicate database `mydb`

## STEP 01 : Add [Replication Filter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db) to `my.cnf` on ServerD

```
[mysqld]
replication-do-db=mydb
```

## STEP 02 : Stop Replication on ServerD

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
mysql> FLUSH TABLES;
mysql> FLUSH LOGS;
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

## STEP 03 : Restart MySQL on ServerD

```
service mysql restart
```

## STEP 04 : Start Replication on ServerD

```
mysql> START SLAVE;
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

After Step 04, the replication filter should appear in the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` of ServerD